# ¿Cómo descompilar un jar sin que dé errores de librerías?

Tags: java

He des-compilado un `.jar` con [jd-gui](/questions/tagged/jd-gui) para poder editar un archivo que daba error. El problema es que al abrir el proyecto con Eclipse para volver a compilarlo había un montón de errores referentes a librerías. Por tanto, volver a compilar el `.jar` para utilizarlo en otro proyecto no funciona.

¿No deberían ir las librerías en el propio `.jar` original? ¿Cómo funciona si no lleva todo lo necesario? ¿Cómo podría solucionarlo sin tener que buscar y añadir todas las librerías?

Comment: 1. no necesariamente. 2. pues los otros jars están en el Classpath 3. te recomiendo que consigas los fuentes originales, lo arregles y lo compiles desde ahí.

Comment: @rnd el contenido de tu comentario es digno de una respuesta.

Answer (score 3):

El descompilador genera los fuentes, no te provee las dependencias del proyecto. Tu tendras que dar esas dependencias a tu proyecto, o bien creando un proyecto maven para tal fin o añadirlas al build path del proyecto o como sea, pero desde luego será porque lo hagas tu.

En el jar que has descompilado dentro del directorio **META-INF** mira a ver si encuentras mas informacion relativo a sus dependencias, si fue construido con Maven puede ser que exista alguna lista de dependencias dentro del fichero *pom.xml*, pero no es seguro.

Answer (score 2):

Añade manualmente las librerías faltantes con Maven. Las dependencias no vienen en el .jar, aunque este es un paquete, no un binario.